# Get rowwise sum across multiple groups of columns based on a partial name match

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

Here's my example input dataset:

```
 df <- data.frame(qw1_A_B_ = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),   
                  qw2_A_B_ = c(3, 6, 9, 12, 15),   
                  qw1_C_D_ = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25),   
                  qw2_C_D_ = c(7, 14, 21, 28, 35))
```

I would like to elaborate the general regular expression to sum each pair of rows sharing qw1 and qw1 with the variable part of column names that match each other. The final out I should obtain is:

```
data.frame(qw1qw2_A_B_ = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25),   
           qw1qw2_A_B_ = c(12, 24, 36, 4, 60))
```

What I just came up with is the following general regular expression by playing with this vector:

```
vector <- c("qw1_A_B_", "qw2_A_B_", "qw1_C_D_", "qw2_C_D_")
vector <- gsub("^qw[12]_(.*)_$", "qw1qw2_\\1", vector)
```

But it is far away from being the wanted output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
do.call(
    cbind,
    lapply(
        split.default(df, sub(".*?_", "", names(df))),
        \(x)
        setNames(
            data.frame(rowSums(x)),
            paste0(
                paste0(sub("_.*", "", names(x)), collapse = ""),
                sub(".*?_", "_", names(x))[1]
            )
        )
    )
)
```

which gives

```
  qw1qw2_A_B_ qw1qw2_C_D_
1           5          12
2          10          24
3          15          36
4          20          48
5          25          60
```

Comment: thank you so much. Could you please explain how did you end up with the following regex `".*?_"`?

Comment: @12666727b9 it is the "lazy mode" search, which means repeating minimal number of times. In your case, the search begins from the beginning but stops when seeing the first underscore `_`

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach by reshaping the dataframe and separating the column names to be able to match the second part (i.e. `A_B_` and `C_D_`) for summarizing. At the end, we return back to wider format.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("row") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-row) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("col", "id"), sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>% 
  summarise(col = paste(col, collapse = ""), 
            value = sum(value, na.rm = T), 
            .by = c(row, id)) %>% 
  unite("name", col, id) %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  select(-row)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   qw1qw2_A_B_ qw1qw2_C_D_
#>         <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1           5          12
#> 2          10          24
#> 3          15          36
#> 4          20          48
#> 5          25          60
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, qw1qw2_A_B_ = rowSums(pick(contains("A_B"))),
           qw1qw2_C_D_ = rowSums(pick(contains("C_D"))),
       .keep = "none")

  qw1qw2_A_B_ qw1qw2_C_D_
1           5          12
2          10          24
3          15          36
4          20          48
5          25          60
```

EDIT: If one wishes to apply it without having to call the variable names directly:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

names(df) |> 
  str_extract("[A-Z]_[A-Z]_") |> 
  unique() |> 
  map(function(x) mutate(df, "qw1qw2_{x}" := rowSums(pick(contains(x))), .keep = "none")) |>
  list_cbind()
```

Comment: You could also use `transmute()` instead of `mutate(..., .keep = "none")`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you mind to explain the meaning of `!!` and in place of what it is used?

Comment: Actually, it was a superfluous use of rlang's tool to inject the name in. I've revised my answer to remove the unneeded `glue` function and the `!!`.